# Как сделать, чтобы пара столбцов выводилась только один раз? [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql

Например, имеем результат запроса:

```
departure_city | arrival_city
----------------+--------------
Москва | Екатеринбург
Екатеринбург | Москва
```

А нужно сделать, чтобы выводилось один раз `Москва - Екатеринбург`.
Вот, какой запрос есть, `DISTINCT` не работает. Нужно как-то модифицировать его. Помогите плиз.

```
SELECT DISTINCT departure_city, arrival_city
FROM routes r
JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
WHERE a.model = 'Боинг 737-300'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Обладают ли обе строки каким-то либо идентификатором помимо названий городов в обратном порядке?

Comment: Да, у каждой строки имеется уникальный "номер рейса".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение своей задачи.

```
SELECT LEAST(departure_city, arrival_city), GREATEST(departure_city, arrival_city)
FROM routes r
JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
WHERE a.model = 'Боинг 737-300'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

С помощью функций `LEAST` и `GREATEST` мы сортируем города, чтобы разнести их по разным столбцам. После, с помощью `GROUP BY` группируем все города и откидываем лишние маршруты.